# regex pattern of repeating characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match words that have all the correct letters but might have repeating ones.

like ddddaaammmnn

`[a-z]*([damn])\\1{1,}[a-z]*` doesn't work because `whhaaaat bananas ddaammn` catches both `whaaat` and `ddaammmn`.

`[a-z]*([d])\\1{1,}[a-z]*` will catch all the d's repeating.

How to I tell the regex to check a pattern or letters in a specific order that could be repeating??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
w+h+a+t+
```

matches `what`, `wwwhaaaattt` and all other variations of `what` as long as the letters are in the right order.